# Multiple labels/textboxes based on what the user entered

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am creating a web form in asp.net and C#.

The form asks the user how many children the user has, and then after clicking on the Proceed button, the application should prompt for each child's name.

I know using a Console Application, the coding will be:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < noOfChildren ; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Child's Name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

How will I code asp.net/C# application to do the same thing, but only displaying the Labels and textboxes the same amount of times the user has entered...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want all the textboxes in a same page, don't you ?

Comment: Yes I do... Same page, same format

Answer (score 1):

In below example it creates only `Textbox` dynamically but you can add your style and label control dynamic based your requirements.

In `Aspx` page, create `form` tag in html body.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                No of Text boxes
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumbers" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
            </td>
    </table>
    <br />      
</div>
```

and in your code behind c# file,

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int noofcontrols = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumbers.Text);
    for (int i = 1; i <= noofcontrols; i++)
    {
        TextBox NewTextBox = new TextBox();
        NewTextBox.ID = "TextBox" + i.ToString();
        NewTextBox.Style["Clear"] = "Both";
        NewTextBox.Style["Float"] = "Left";
        NewTextBox.Style["Top"] = "25px";
        NewTextBox.Style["Left"] = "100px";
        //form1 is a form in my .aspx file with runat=server attribute
        form1.Controls.Add(NewTextBox);
    }
}
```

I assume this is what you want.

[Reference](http://www.dotnetpickles.com/2014/02/cnet-dynamically-create-textbox-in.html)

Comment: Please put the code directly in your answer instead of through a link. Your answer should be complete here, and links should only be used for extra or supplementary information.

Comment: Based on community feedback and I also feel in same way, so i edited my answer.